# If I change the domain of my site, what happens with the cookies?

Tags: http, cookies, browser

We have a site where we are using cookies for tracking purposes. Now we are thinking in changing the domain of our site but we will want to still recognise User's sessions from the old domain. Is this possible?

Comment: The users browsers will not send  cookies from the old domain to the new domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't retrieve cookies that belong to other domains.** As a workaround (in case you can still use the old domain); by creating an iframe inside http://newdomain.com from http://olddomain.com, you can get cookies and send to parent via postMessage.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are affected by same origin policy but you can bypass it with CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing).

CORS is a play between browser and server. 
Basic idea is allow ajax request to cross domains but you can use to share cookies(security measures should be taken).

Browser send a request with Origin header.
If the server allows the request then it reply with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the value of origin.
If the server doesn’t reply with the header or don’t match Origin with  Access-Control-Allow-Origin browser disallow the request.

But it doesn’t send cookies or something like that by default(you have to add “allow-credentials” extra header).

With CORS you can share the session between domains adding to new domain server the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://original-domain.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

More info about CORS:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
- http://quickleft.com/blog/cookies-with-my-cors

Comment: I don't see how a server configuration can affect the browser to send cookies to the domain they are not owned. This would be a very security issue.

Comment: @fguillen About security I think you could read this link at [Stackoverflow](http://goo.gl/Zsrl0o) or this one at [OWASP](http://goo.gl/36PaEO)

Comment: As I understand the whole **CORS** is a system to prevent browsers to access to a not-authorised server resources. But in the cookies context the security concern is in the other way around. As I understand the **CORS** configuration you are suggesting will send cookies to the domain _original-domain.com_ in a site under other domain. But it will send cookies owned by the domain _original-domain.com_ and not cookies from another domain.. What I'm looking is to catch cookies owned from one domain from a site hosted in another domain.